# Use Ansible facts in an Ansible ad-hoc command

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-ad-hoc

Is it possible to use what would normally be included in `ansible_facts` in an Ansible adhoc command?

For example, I have a file at `/tmp/myFile` on all of my servers and I'd like to do:

```
ansible all -i [inventory file] -m fetch -a "src=/tmp/myFile dest=myFile-[insert ansible_hostname here]"
```

Without having to make a whole playbook for it.

Comment: Why not just give it a try and see?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I have given it a try. Usual mechanism for accessing it doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you cannot refer to ansible facts in ansible cli. This is because when you run `ansible ... -m fetch` you are not getting the facts of the host(s) you are running on. The facts are gathered with `setup` module ( you can try that by doing `ansible ... -m setup`. 
Anyway, this can be addressed with a simple playbook like

```
# file: fetchfile.yml
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
    - fetch: src=/tmp/myFile dest=myFile-{{ inventory_hostname }}

$ ansible-playbook -i [inventory_file] fetchfile.yml
```

`ansible-playbook` runs the `setup` module implicitly, so you will have access to all the facts as variables.