# Ansible facts in a single file

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to collect servers inventory with ansible using the following command:

```
ansible all -m setup -a --tree facts/
```

but this is generating a lot os single files for each host under facts folder.

I would like all servers output in a unique file, I noticed the content is similar to json.
I want to use it to read in python later and use the hostname as keys for the python dictionary and just read the the facts regarding each host collected.

Is there something like below??

```
ansible localhost -m setup -a --tree --single-file facts/
```

Comment: You can get the help from below stack-overflow link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484980/use-ansible-facts-in-an-ansible-ad-hoc-command

Answer (score 3):

This playbook will copy all the gather fact content in `/tmp/ansible_facts_details.json` file on the host machine. You can run it from location where inventory file is located in the control machine (where Ansible is installed).

1. Command to run playbook is `ansible-playbook  playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml`
2. Command to check playbook syntax is `ansible-playbook  playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml --syntax-check`
3. Command to do runtime debug `ansible-playbook -vvv playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml`

> ```
> - name: Play to get the gathre facts content
>   hosts: DEV1
>   tasks:
>   - name: print ansible_facts
>     debug:
>      var: ansible_facts["kernel"]
>   - name: Copy ansible facts to a file.
>     copy:
>      content: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
>      dest: /tmp/ansible_facts_details.json
> ```

Answer (score 2):

According [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables), add to playbok next task

```
  tasks:
  - name: Generate report
    local_action:
      module: copy
      dest: ./hosts-OS-version.txt
      content: |
          {% for host in groups['all'] %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['distribution'] is defined %}
          {{ '%-50s' | format(host) }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['distribution'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['distribution_version'] }}
          {% else %}
          {{ '%-50s' | format(host) }} undefined
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--forks 1` option in first ansible command.

Comment: Did you mean the below:
`ansible localhost -m setup --forks 1 --tree.` ?

still outputting 1 file for each host.